# Agreement between raters with kappa, using tidyverse and looping functions to pivot the data (data set)

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

Let's say that in my research, each student was evaluated by several raters two times during an academic year. Pretty common in my field. Therefore, I have a dataset with the following format:

[image]

My goal is to check the agreement between these evaluations. I can pivot the dataset to check the agreement of all raters for each student.

```
ds_test %>% 
  select(rater, student_1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(., names_from = "rater", values_from = "student_1", values_fn = list(student_1 = list)) %>% 
  unchop(everything()) %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("rater") %>% 
  {irr::kappa2(.[, c("V1", "V2")], weight = "unweighted")}
```

[image: agreement]

However, my goal is to have a function that I can dynamically check all students at once. With the present code, I have to change the **student_1** argument.

I know this is possible and I have a clue that I'll have to nest the dataset. However, I'm not being able to solve this puzzle right now.

I would like to remain within the tidyverse environment.
All codes are here:

```
ds_test <- structure(list(rater = c("rater30", "rater14", "rater24", "rater31", 
                                    "rater1", "rater15", "rater32", "rater11", "rater34", "rater35", 
                                    "rater15", "rater3", "rater27", "rater9"), student_1 = c("C", 
                                                                                             "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"
                                    ), student_2 = c("D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                     "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), student_3 = c("A", "A", "D", "A", "A", 
                                                                                             "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), student_4 = c("C", 
                                                                                                                                                         "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
                                                                                             ), student_5 = c("A", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                              "A", "C", "B", "B", "B"), student_6 = c("D", "A", "B", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                                                                      "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "A"), student_7 = c("B", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "D", "A", "C"
                                                                                                                                                      ), student_8 = c("A", "B", "D", "B", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "C", "A", "D", "B", "B"), student_9 = c("A", "D", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               "D", "D", "D", "D", NA, "C", "C", "B", "D"), student_10 = c("B", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B"
                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), student_11 = c("A", "C", "D", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "C", "C", "A", "C", "C"), student_12 = c("A", "B", NA, "D", "C", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B"), student_13 = c("A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "A", NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ), student_14 = c("C", "D", NA, NA, "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "A", "A", "D", "D", "D"), student_15 = c("C", NA, NA, NA, "A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "C", "B", "B", "B", NA, "B", "A", "B", "B"), student_16 = c("C", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "D", "C", "A", NA, "B"), 
                          student_17 = c("D", NA, NA, NA, "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                         "D", "C", "A", NA, "D"), student_18 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", 
                                                                                 "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", NA, "C"), student_19 = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                             NA, NA, NA, "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", NA, "A"
                                                                                 ), student_20 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                   "D", "D", "D", NA, "D"), student_21 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                           NA, "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", NA, NA, "B"), student_22 = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", NA, NA, "A"), 
                          student_23 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", "C", "D", NA, 
                                         "B", NA, NA, "C"), student_24 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                           "A", "A", "A", NA, "A", NA, NA, "A"), student_25 = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", "D", NA, "A", NA, NA, "D"), 
                          student_26 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "C", "A", "C", 
                                         "C", NA, NA, "C"), student_27 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                           "D", "D", "B", NA, "D", NA, NA, NA), student_28 = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


ds_test %>% 
  select(rater, student_1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(., names_from = "rater", values_from = "student_1", values_fn = list(student_1 = list)) %>% 
  unchop(everything()) %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("rater") %>% 
  {irr::kappa2(.[, c("V1", "V2")], weight = "unweighted")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you get the data in long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result <- ds_test %>%
             pivot_longer(cols = -rater, values_to = 'value1') %>%
             mutate(value2 = value1) %>%
             group_by(name) %>%
            summarise(answer = list(irr::kappa2(select(cur_data(),value1,value2),
                                      weight = "unweighted")))
```

where each individual result can be looked as `result$answer[[1]]`, `result$answer[[2]]` etc.

Comment: It worked! Thanks much! it worked. Is there any way to print all results?

Comment: Isn't that `result$answer` ?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
# I had to re-create the data frame because in your reprex there were no repeated raters :)

ds_test = tibble(
  rater = rep(paste0('rater', 1:5), 2),
  student_1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = TRUE),
  student_2 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = TRUE),
  student_3 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = TRUE),
  student_4 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = TRUE),
  student_5 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = TRUE)
)


ds_test %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=2:ncol(.), names_to = 'student', values_to = 'grade') %>%
  group_by(rater, student) %>% mutate(n = paste0('rating_', row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = grade)
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 25 x 4
# Groups:   rater, student [25]
   rater  student   rating_1 rating_2
   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   
 1 rater1 student_1 D        D       
 2 rater1 student_2 C        B       
 3 rater1 student_3 B        A       
 4 rater1 student_4 D        E       
 5 rater1 student_5 E        C       
 6 rater2 student_1 C        B       
 7 rater2 student_2 A        D       
 8 rater2 student_3 D        D       
 9 rater2 student_4 A        B       
10 rater2 student_5 D        A
```

Essentially, I'm doing a little trick by keeping track of the number of times that each (rater, student) combination appears in the dataframe and storing it into a new column `n`, which I then use as names for `pivot_wider()`.

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. I see what you doing there.